# using not working for eponymous class?

Tags: c#

I've got a class named Hasher in a namespace named Hasher. So the fully-qualified name would be:

```
Hasher.Hasher ...
```

I'm try to use the Hasher class in an external assembly (C#). I've imported the namespace into my class:

```
using Hasher;
```

But when I try to use the Hasher class the compiler will not find it.

```
using Hasher;

namespace Test {
  ///<summary>
  ///This is a test class for HasherTest and is intended
  ///to contain all HasherTest Unit Tests
  ///</summary>
  [TestClass()]
  public class HasherTest {

    ///<summary>
    ///A test for GenerateFromRawData with null seed
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException( typeof( ArgumentNullException ) )]
    public void GenerateFromRawDataTest_NullSeed() {
      byte[] seed = null;
      byte[] salt = null;

      seed = null;
      salt = null;

      Hasher.GenerateFromRawData( seed, salt );
    }

}
```

Generates:

```
Error   The type or namespace name 'GenerateFromRawData' does not exist in the namespace 'Hasher' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  M:\j41833b_UR403088_ReportingDotNet\ReportingDotNet\src\AG385\_UnitTest\HasherTest.cs   _UnitTest
```

Am I not using "using" correctly? (My primary language is VB.NET, so my C# is a bit rusty. A cursory examination of the MSDN documentation didn't reveal anything)

EDIT: This works fine.

```
namespace Test {
  ///<summary>
  ///This is a test class for HasherTest and is intended
  ///to contain all HasherTest Unit Tests
  ///</summary>
  [TestClass()]
  public class HasherTest {

    ///<summary>
    ///A test for GenerateFromRawData with null seed
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException( typeof( ArgumentNullException ) )]
    public void GenerateFromRawDataTest_NullSeed() {
      byte[] seed = null;
      byte[] salt = null;

      seed = null;
      salt = null;

      Hasher.Hasher.GenerateFromRawData( seed, salt );
    }

}
```

Comment: [Do not name a class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Is your Hasher class public? is the GenerateFromRawData static? you are calling it as a static method. And yes, namespaces should be different from class names.

Comment: A good name for the namespace would be "Hashing".

Comment: Thanks @asawyer - your referenced article gave me what I need. Interestingly, VB.NET has never thrown this error. (I'm only using C# because, somehow, my Test project template for VB.NET seems to have been horked). I'd love to give you credit if you post an answer.

Comment: Wow, you don't see the word "eponymous" used much these days. :)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Eric answered it not me. Make your changes and post it as an answer, that would be the most helpful for visitors in the future.

Comment: @Olivier - Thanks. Hashing is a good name. I used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @asawyer for the following article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

There are two ansers. One, using extern alias:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212(v=vs.100).aspx

Two, rename the Hasher namespace. (This is recommended when you have control of the source code and it's the option I chose.)

Comment: what is eponymous class? I have heard it first time ,even google is not helping me :/

Comment: @dotNetSoldier An eponymous album is named after the band that created it. I used the term loosely to refer to a class with the same name as the namespace in which it is defined.

Comment: ohhh I was puzzled and consider it some kinda design pattern :)